# Writing option bytes of STM32F091RC on raspberry pi using ST-LINK/V2

Tags: linux

I am building application which will (besides other things) write flash memory and option bytes of STM32F091RC.

Application will run on raspberry pi, OS raspbian 4.7.7 armv6l.

I am currently successfully using `st-flash` utility (https://github.com/texane/stlink) to write data to flash memory using this command:

```
st-flash write firmware.bin 0x8000000
```

Now I also need to write option bytes too. I thought

```
st-flash write optionBytes.bin 0x1FFFF800
```

could work (just write to address of option bytes), but it does not. Apparently, writing option bytes is different than writing flash memory and probably it's not possible to achieve it using st-flash?

Are there any utilities which are able to write option bytes and can run:

- raspberry/arm
- unix/debian based
- St-link/V2
- STM32F091RC
- can run from commandline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question unrelated to linux and raspberry pi. Your aim is programming of option bytes at `0x1FFFF800`. Go to [RM0091](http://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00031936.pdf) at page 937 (A.2.5 - A.2.7). There are code examples of unlocking, programming, erasing of option bytes. **This code will be executed on your STM32F091RC**. So you can see this is not trivial operation. I see 2 easy ways to perform the programming option bytes.

1) If you do your firmware, then edit the source code. Perform the programming of option bytes at first execution of new firmware.

2) Programm device with *firmware.bin*. Make little program that perform programming of option bytes. Run it from SRAM. For this link all sections at SRAM (at `0x20000000`). See *README.md* of `st-flash`.

Comment: Finally we ended up using solution 2). We got little program from external engineer and we are writing it to stm32 using this project: https://github.com/pavelrevak/pystlink using command `python3 pystlink.py reset:halt write:optionBytes.srec set:pc:0x20000a94 run`

Comment: Neither option works for me: I need to write the option bytes to make it boot from user-flash instead of "bootloader". 
I have a low-pincount device, so my hardware doesnt' implement a dedicated boot-pin.  Suggestions?